# Good place to sleep in (or near) Miami's airport?

Tags: airports, hotels, accommodation, miami

I will soon have a series of flights including a 13 hour nightly stop in Miami and I'm willing to pay a little more if it means a comfortable bed to sleep in.

Is there any commendable place near (or even inside) the airport where I can have a shower and a room for a reasonable price?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As you should know, Stack Exchange is very ill-suited to requests for suggestions, tips, recommendations, or other open-ended lists, in particular because everyone has a different opinion of what is a "reasonable" tradeoff of price against convenience, amenities, cleanliness, and so on. The various hotel review sites are better equipped. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: We probably shouldn't recommend anything, but we can certainly discuss the practical alternatives given the constraints of time and location.

Comment: I spent 30 hours in the airport :)  Was quite nice and quiet at night, plenty of benches/floor area :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is probably to broad, you should define 'near', 'reasonable', and 'comfortable' a bit more specific.

If you look at hostels, you can get several to chose from for under 20 $, most are towards the beaches, about 10 miles from the airport.
If you want a class up, like a Motel 6 or similar, they start around 60 $; some are less than 3 miles from MIA.
Some might have shuttles, or you can Uber or rent a car, and that each costs different.

Weekends and seasons will change that, upwards of course.